# How to add a menu for a grid panel on right click in Ext.NET from code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ext.net

I have created a grid panel in code behind using C# and I want to add a menu on the right click button on any row of this grid panel using c# not Ext.NET tags. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U can use `RowContextMenu`
Here is the [references](http://examples.ext.net/#/Toolbar/Menu/Context_Menu/) from the offical web site of the ext.net and [forum  page](http://forums.ext.net/showthread.php?1294-GridPanel-Context-Menu)